# Why hyperref's \url may be used in preamble within a macro but not within a box?

Tags: hyperref, boxes, urls, preamble

The following MWE, where a macro involving `hyperref`'s `\url` is defined in the preamble, works like a charm:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%
\newcommand\testmacro{\url{http://macro.org}}
%
\newsavebox{\testbox}
%
\begin{document}
\testmacro

\savebox{\testbox}{\url{http://boxes.org}}
\usebox{\testbox}
\end{document}
```

But, as soon as the box definition `\savebox{\testbox}{\url{http://boxes.org}}` is as well moved in the preamble, the following error message arises:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\hyper@linkurl ...tionraw >>}\relax \Hy@colorlink 
                                                  \@urlcolor #1Hy@xspace@en...
```

Hence my question: why `hyperref`'s `\url` may be used in preamble within a macro but not within a box?

Comment: @JosephWright: Did you move the \savebox to the preamble? I get the error Denis mentions and have to use `\AtBeginDocument{\savebox{\testbox}{\url{http://boxes.org}}}` (and it is not surprising as hyperref delays a lot of definitions to the begin of the document).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Indeed, `\AtBeginDocument` does the trick. I agree `hyperref` delays a lot of definitions to the begin of the document, but why something like `\AtBeginDocument` is necessary for the box and not for the macro?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A macro definition is not *executed* at the point of definition, you can go

```
\newcommand\foo{\any old \rubbish }
```

and as long as `{}` match up `\foo` is defined. You may get an error later if you try to use `\foo`, but you get no error at this point, and if `\any` and `\rubbish` are defined by the time you use `\foo` there is no error.

Conversely a box is typeset as it is saved (which may expand macros)

```
 \savebox\mybox{\any old \rubbish }
```

will generate undefined command errors at that point as it can not typeset the material into a box.

Comment: Is a box really *typeset* as it is saved? In such a case, `\savebox\mybox{any old rubbish}` (without any macro) in the preamble should give an error, isn't it?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé yes it is typeset and no if you keep things simple you can usually typeset small amounts in the preamble as most classes at least set up `\normalfont` to be 10pt cmr, however it may typeset the wrong thing as many packages delay setting up fonts and math and languages to `begin{document}`